# JTable cell losing value when it's clicked to open a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, jcombobox

Got a current project going on and I need to set all cells from a column in a `JTable` to JComboBoxes. Their items are the same for all rows and are extracted from a SQL Server table. When the program runs, it fills the whole `JTable` with the values from a SQL Server table. Everything is ok at this point but when a user clicks the column to show the `JComboBox` and the items show up, **the value that was on that cell is overwritten by the `JComboBox`.** What I wanted to happen is opening the JComboBox with the values and "suggesting" to the user the last value in that cell (the one that disappeared), dropping down and selecting the said value.

Is there a way to doing this easily?

This is how I'm adding the items to all the `JComboBoxes`

`TableColumn col_cod_tipo_verba = jtab_verba.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
        JComboBox box_tab_tipo_verba = new JComboBox();
        ResultSet rs = Glob.conecta_sql().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM tab_tipo_verba").executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            box_tab_tipo_verba.addItem(rs.getString(1));
        }
        col_cod_tipo_verba.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(box_tab_tipo_verba));`

Comment: What if you call box_tab_tipo_verba.setSelectedItem(theCellVaue) after filling?

Comment: But how am I supposed to know the CellValue? The part of the code I posted is static, it just turns all the JTable's cells of that column to be a JComboBox. But your answer may work with another bit of code; I'm gonna try it and report back in a sec

Comment: I tried getting the value that was in the cell with a MouseListener, but didn't work. The Listener doesn't trigger if I click the JComboBox directly. I need another way of getting the data that was on the cell.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the method

```
Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                      boolean isSelected,
                                      int row, int column)
```

In the call `col_cod_tipo_verba.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(box_tab_tipo_verba));` and `after super.getTableCellEditorComponent` use the value to be set in the editor

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now this has helped me getting the value of each cell **before** it was overwritten by the JComboBox; Now I need to set the object in the JComboBox equals to the String I got.

Comment: Now I need to set the value of the cell as the String I got, thus "deleting" for lack of a better word. Can anyone tell me how to do that? I am open to other ways of solving the whole problem though.

Comment: @MVR when an answer helps you with your problem it is necessary to mark it. Because may be it is the common problem and others can use it before they ask a redundant question.

Comment: If you get the value just call box_tab_tipo_verba.setSelectedItem(value)

Comment: @STaefi when I'm done with my question, I'm going to mark the one that was most helpful to me.

Comment: @StanislavL since this is related to a work project, I'll try it monday most probably and report back.